# random order's status is changed automatically to "completed" from "processing" in wordpress woocommerce site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Few days ago some of the orders changes its status to completed automatically. it shows some of the orders were change its status on same date & time but some of the orders has different date & time of the status change. There is no common thing between the orders whose status changed automatically. Some of the orders has cash on delivery and some of the orders paid through payment gateways. How to detect the cause of this problem.  Is this problem occurs due to I am not updating the plugins.

Comment: Please check if have a active plugin like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autocomplete-woocommerce-orders/) or some codes in your functions.php, like [this one](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automatically-complete-orders/)

Comment: No such plugin is installed... not all the orders status get changed... only few of them are changed randomly